# Is it valid to do a Bayesian analysis on an old paper which didn't publish a Bayesian analysis?

Tags: bayesian, statistical-significance

Is Bayesian Analysis, and the judgement it allows on the chance of a true effect being significant despite an overall analysis being not statistically significant, something that can be retrospectively applied to published data?

Comment: "Bayesian Analysis, and the judgement it allows on the chance of a true effect being significant" what does this mean?

Comment: "something that can be retrospectively applied to published data?" If you have the data, then you can do it. A question is whether you want to do it. What is it supposed to help with?

Comment: In case you're asking about Bayesian *reanalysis* of originally frequentist studies: yes, this is routinely done. [Here's a recent review article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8439199/) on that topic.